# Why isn't JObject converting the JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, jsonschema

I don't know if I have done this correctly or not, but I have the following class to try to validate and parse JSON:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    internal const string UserResetDataScheme = @"{
      'title' : 'UserResetDataModel',
      'type' : 'object',
      'properties': {
        'Role' : {'type' : 'integer'},
        'Email' : {'type' : 'string'},
      },
      required: [ 'Role', 'Email']
    }";

    internal static T TryParseJson<T>(this string json, string schema) where T : new()
    {
        var parsedSchema = JSchema.Parse(schema);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        return jObject.IsValid(parsedSchema) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json) : default(T);
    }
}
```

Most of the time the schema check works fine, but sometimes I need to deserialize a string like this:

> "\"User sent null or empty data\""

In that case the schema validation should return false. However, I get an error when I call `JObject.Parse`:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '',

I am using the schema which I have shown above.

If I understand this right, I can't parse to string? But then what do I do in this case?  How can I validate the JSON is incorrect if I can't parse it?

(JSON which conforms to this schema parses correctly.)

Comment: What is the JSON string you are trying to parse/validate against the schema?

Comment: I wrote this line: -- well I check schema works fine but sometimes I need to deserialize the string like `"\"User sent null or empty data\""`

Comment: OK, I see now what is going on.  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because `"\"User sent null or empty data\""` is not a JSON object, so it cannot be parsed by `JObject.Parse`.  Instead you should use [`JToken.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm).  This method can handle any kind of JSON -- objects, arrays and simple values.  The [`IsValid`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_SchemaExtensions_IsValid.htm) extension method is defined to work on `JToken`, so it should still work fine with this change.

As an aside, when the `JToken` validates successfully, you don't need to deserialize the JSON a second time with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`.  You can convert the token to your object directly using [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) instead.

So in other words, change this code:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
return jObject.IsValid(parsedSchema) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json) : default(T);
```

To this:

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
return jToken.IsValid(parsedSchema) ? jToken.ToObject<T>() : default(T);
```

To be extra safe you could put a try/catch block around the parsing.  That way if you get a string that isn't even JSON at all, you can handle that as well.  So then you would have:

```
internal static T TryParseJson<T>(this string json, string schema) where T : new()
{
    var parsedSchema = JSchema.Parse(schema);
    try
    {
        var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
        return jToken.IsValid(parsedSchema) ? jToken.ToObject<T>() : default(T);
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        // optionally log the exception here
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any problems (return default), thank's for your answer)!